USB WIFI adapter RTL8188GU drivers
I have a usb-wifi adapter that shows under lsusb as
 Bus 001 Device 025: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188GU 802.11n WLAN Adapter (Driver CDROM Mode)

I built https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8188gu-dkms-git but it did not produce the module expected
> modprobe rtl8188gu
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8188gu not found in directory /lib/modules/6.9.7-arch1-1

so after a comment on that page I installed https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8xxxu-dkms-git
:> lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8xxxu              303104  0
btrtl                  32768  1 btusb
mac80211             1597440  2 iwlmvm,rtl8xxxu
bluetooth            1101824  16 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,btusb
cfg80211             1363968  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,rtl8xxxu

But after reboot it does not associate with the network device.

what does dmesg | grep rtl8 show?

@likewise     [   86.104568] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu [   92.798637] r8152 4-1.4:1.0: load rtl8153b-2 v2 04/27/23 successfully

Did you notice this comment at the Arch link above for rtl8xxxu-dkms-git?
"I recently had problems getting my RTL8188GU wireless USB adapter working using the rtl8xxxu-dkms-git package from the AUR. After some research, I found that the usb_modeswitch package is needed to change the adapter's mode to wireless mode. After installing this package, the adapter worked correctly."

@nomadrc Ah! That could explain why my boot stalls when the adapter is plugged in. It appears as a bootable USB storage device ? To switch the mode usb_modeswitch needs a message. Do you have that or know where I can get it. It doesn't come up in my searches.

@StephenBoston : I would install the package and dependencies if you didn't already, Arch package comment for the rtl8xxxu-dkms says this:
"If your usb wifi adapter is based on a RTL8188GU or RTL8192FU chip, you may need to use the command `usb_modeswitch` or `eject` to switch it to "Wifi Mode" first.

Before installing this package, make sure that your system has the corresponding kernel headers installed."

Man page here: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/usb-modeswitch/usb_modeswitch.1.en.html

I believe that modprobe command should be
modprobe 8188gu

